# SVG : Confusion about relative path coordinates

Tags: svg, coordinates

I'm trying to cut up a long SVG path generated by inkscape into several smaller paths. Specifically, I am cutting up this path:

```
"m 42.333333,13.895833 c 0,21.166668 21.166666,19.843751 21.166666,19.843751 h 9.260417 c 0,0 19.84375,-11.906251 13.229166,7.9375 -6.614583,19.84375 -13.229166,31.75 -33.072916,21.166667 C 33.072916,52.260417 31.75,13.895833 31.75,13.895833"
```

The output I generate at the moment are the following paths:

```
"M 42.333333,13.895833 c 0,21.166668 21.166666,19.843751 21.166666,19.843751"
"M 63.499999,33.739584 l 9.260417,0"
"M 72.760416,33.739584 c 0,0 19.84375,-11.906251 13.229166,7.9375 -6.614583,19.84375 -13.229166,31.75 -33.072916,21.166667"
"M 39.6875,54.906251 c -6.61458400000001,-2.645834 -7.93750000000001,-41.010418 -7.93750000000001,-41.010418"
```

This is not correct. You can see the difference between input and output [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kBdK.jpg).

As you can see, almost all points are correct, except that the fourth path of the output does not start at the same point that the corresponding part of the original path does. This is probably caused by some error in my understanding of how SVG path coordinates exactly work.

I arrived at the starting point (39.6875,54.906251) for the fourth path as follows:

We start at (42.33333,13.895833). We then curve to relative position (21.166666,19.843751), so that gives us absolute position (42.33333+21.166666,13.895833+19.843751) = (63.499996,33.739584).
The path is then extended with a horizontal line with relative x coordinate 9.260417. So that gives new absolute position (63.499996 + 9.260417, 33.739584 + 0 ) = (72.760413,33.739584). We then curve to relative position (-33.072916,21.166667). Giving the start position for the fourth path as (72.760413-33.072916,33.739584+21.166667) = (39.6875,54.906251) (with some rounding).

Why is this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself.

The problem was caused due to the third curve actually being a polybezier consisting of 2 cubic curves. The coordinates of that second cubic bezier should be relative to its starting point, rather than the starting point of the complete polybezier.